# Node.js with express.js. Users can register using the same data twice if they send post requests fast enough

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, express

I am using Node.js with the express.js framework on top of it and MySql database.

I have an endpoint for registration that takes 3 params: 
Email, username, and password
And then it queries the database using SELECT to see if the username or email are taken. And if not it continues to hash the password, create a new row in the database, send an email confirmation and so on.

The problem is when someone submits two post request quickly since it takes some time to process the data insertion the request let two users have the same username/email.
Basically what is happening is that the second request query the database before the first request even insert the data (the new user) and therefore the results the second request return are that the username and the email are free.

I was wondering how can I prevent issues like that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a race condition like this, the place where the buck should stop is the database itself.  So, you should add a unique constraint on the `username` field, if you don't already have one:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT username_unique UNIQUE (username);
```

What will happen now if two threads come in at almost the same time, is that each request will work its way through the code.  But only one request will obtain a lock to write the new user record to the table.  The other request would fail with a database error, which your Node application should able to catch.

Note that you might also want a unique constraint on the email field.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making modifications to the schema I suggest you deal with this in your node APP.
Using mutex locks are the ideal approach to solving these kinds of problems. There are different packages like [redlock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redlock) etc to solve these issues although redlock needs redis to work. There are other modules that don't require redis.
Also have a read [Mutex locks in node](https://medium.com/@the1mills/a-better-mutex-for-node-js-4b4897fd9f11)